# How to preauthorize access to a Http.InboundGateway?

Tags: spring-security, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I know its possible to add a @PreAuthorize annotation to a Rest Controller...

```
@RestController
public class WebController {
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('Foo')")
    @GetMapping("/restricted")
    public ResponseEntity<String> restricted() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Restricted section");
    }
}
```

How can one preauthorize access to a Spring Integration Http.inbound gateway? I know I could add in a component to the Integration flow and add the annotation on a transformer or service activator method but I'd rather not have a separate object for that.

```
@Bean
//@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('Foo')") ?
public HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway restrictedGateway() {
    return Http.inboundGateway("/restricted")
            ...
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway restrictedGateway) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(restrictedGateway)
            .transform(source -> "Restricted section")
            .get();
}
```

Comment: Would I need an intermediate "securedChannel" after the gateway in the flow to acheive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I think you are right by looking at https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/security.htm where it allows channel to be declared `@Secured`
- Even if we think about spring security on a normal spring boot app without integration, it is at filter level so it seems to make sense as I consider `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway` as a listener for http requests

Can you try

```
    @Bean
    @SecuredChannel(interceptor = "channelSecurityInterceptor", sendAccess = "ROLE_XXX")
    public SubscribableChannel secureChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow myFlow(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway 
                                  restrictedGateway) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(restrictedGateway)
            .channel(secureChannel())
            .transform(source -> "Restricted section")
            .get();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for sendAccess to be a hasAuthority?

Comment: Sorry. I don't have a sample app to play with. But I was checking the code `sendAccess` param is gets passed to in the spring security source code. It is going as config attribute to `accessDecisionManager` which is the same thing used in when you have spring security without sprint integration. so I in my understanding, it should work for `hasAuthority`